# Remove space before and after enumerate

Tags: enumerate

I am a beginner with LaTeX and I am trying to typeset my Resume. I am using {enumerate} to create a list to describe some work experience. However, there is unnecessary space before and after the list that I cannot get rid of. Does anybody have any suggestions?

```
\section{ABC}
\begin{supertabular}{ p{2.0cm} | p{16.0cm}}
\raggedright {\texttt{May.~2013} --}      & \textbf{Research Assistant}\\
\raggedright {\texttt{Jan.~2014}}         & XYZ University\\

&{\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,label=$\bullet$]
\item Prepared ...
\item Analysed ...
\item Researched ...
\end{enumerate}}\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
```

Output: 
[image: Resume section]

Comment: You're using [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem), it seems. Add the option `topsep=0pt` or `nosep` to reduce the space. There's also no need for ``\\`` after `\end{enumerate}`.

Comment: @Werner The `\\ ` is ending the tabular row, isn't it?

Comment: @cfr: True. I missed that...

Answer (score 3):

Use the following command to omit vertical space (in your case before the enumeration):

```
\vspace{-1pc}
```

For adjusting the amount of space you want to omit, you may alter the number -1.
Also, you may define a shortcut for this command using \newcommand or \def in the permeable if you need to use it very much

Comment: This is not a good way to ensure consistent formatting. It would be better not to add the vertical space in the first place so you don't have to figure out how much to compensate by and don't have to change it if that alters. Please don't recommend the use of `\def` in LaTeX documents. It is not at all wise. `\newcommand*` is a good alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Please always add a complete example. It is a waste of time trying to figure out which packages and settings you've used for the fragment you give to produce the output you show.

The best way to kill the vertical spacing the list itself adds is to use the keys provided by `enumitem`: `topsep`, `parsep`, `partopsep`, along with `noitemsep` to kill the spacing between items.

However, the list still gets additional space because it starts a new line, as usual, and there is nothing on the line already within this cell.

Hence, the easiest solution is not to put it in a cell of its own in the first place:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{article}
\usepackage{supertabular,enumitem}
\begin{document}
\section{ABC}
\begin{supertabular}{ p{2.0cm} | p{16.0cm}}
  \raggedright {\texttt{May.~2013} --}      & \textbf{Research Assistant}\\
  \raggedright {\texttt{Jan.~2014}}         & XYZ University
  \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,label=$\bullet$,noitemsep,partopsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt]
      \item Prepared ...
      \item Analysed ...
      \item Researched ...
    \end{enumerate}\\
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
\end{supertabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: kill vertical spacing]